# How do I start an nginx service using a custom nginx.conf file?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi as a jellyfin media server.

I'd like to access the device over the internet from a domain I own.

[I've followed the jellyfin instructions](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/networking/nginx.html) for setting up an nginx conf file. The instructions indicated I should create a new file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/jellyfin.conf`. However, they don't indicate what I should do next. I assumed that nginx just sort of "knows" to look for custom conf files in its `conf.d` directory, but if I do `sudo service nginx start`, I'm not seeing the results I expect (a working reverse proxy). Then again, I'm also not really sure how to debug.

If I do `sudo nginx -t` I get

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

So, I guess that means that my custom conf file isn't getting picked up? But, if I try to do

```
nginx -t /etc/nginx/conf.d/jellyfin.conf
```

I get an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/jellyfin.conf:2
```

Anyway, that's not necessarily what I want to do: I want nginx running as a service, because I also don't know how to quit out of SSH without closing a program I've started from the given terminal.

How can I make the nginx service pick up my custom conf file?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't reading your config file? You were exceptionally vague about this.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess it's hard to say really! It's not working right, for one thing, but I'd love to know how to check for sure. I thought by doing `nginx -t /etc/nginx/conf.d/jellyfin.conf ` I was checking?

Comment: Run `nginx -T`. Every file that is used will be shown.

Comment: I guess I'd like to confirm that nginx is even picking up on my conf file before I debug further why it isn't working.

Comment: ah! Ok, it is picking up on it, never mind! # configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/jellyfin.conf:

Comment: @CalebJay Usually `*.conf` files from `/etc/nginx/conf.d` are included within the main `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` configuration file under **http** context (look for the `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` line), they are not standalone configurations.

Comment: I suppose I could change my question a bit to be "how do I tell if nginx is using my conf file?" Then Michael can add their answer, though I guess it'll be a duplicate at that point. Otherwise I suppose we should close it - I feel weird deleting it outright.

Comment: the answer is quite simple, in the main section where you placed the jelly file are only main items accepted but not server, this is due that there's also a site-enabled where server is allowed but not all main parts, you can see that if you look into nginx.conf for "include" and you will see the magic